# How does $\int _1^3\:\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x(4-x))}dx=1$?

Tags: calculus, integration

This integral below is given, I did graph it using Desmos and realized that from 1 to 3 the value is exactly 1 but I have no way to prove this yet as I was unable to actually integrate the function. Any idea is welcome!

$$\int _1^3\:\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{\ln\left(x\left(4-x\right)\right)}dx=1$$

Comment: You should probably use $$I = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(b+a-x) dx$$ which implies $$2I = \int_{a}^{b} [f(x) + f(b+a-x)] dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I=\int_{1}^{3}\frac{\ln x}{\ln(x(4-x))}dx.$ Consider the substitution
$y=4-x$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
I & = & -\int_{3}^{1}\frac{\ln(4-y)}{\ln(y(4-y))}dy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{3}\frac{\ln(4-y)}{\ln(y(4-y))}dy.
\end{eqnarray*}
Adding them up, we have $2I=\int_{1}^{3}\frac{\ln y+\ln(4-y)}{\ln(y(4-y))}dy=\int_{1}^{3}dy=2$.
Therefore $I=1$.